# How to read csv file with semicolon as delimiter

Tags: csv

Suppose I have the following `scientists.csv` file:

```
name,surname;age
Albert,Einstein;133
Marie,Curie;145
Thomas,Edison;165
```

Now I want to use `;` as the only delimiter:

[image]

How can I do that?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{scientists.csv}
\end{document}
```

It produces:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean: `\csvautotabular[separator=semicolon]{scientists.csv}`..?

Comment: @jon But it gives `pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/csv/separator' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...abular[separator=semicolon]{scientists.csv}`.

Comment: Sounds like you have an old version of the package. Your document works for me with `csvsimple.sty    2013/09/25 version 1.07 LaTeX CSV file processing` (according to `\listfiles`)

Comment: @jon OK, I fixed it by downloading it from [here](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.sty).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the reported problem can be fixed by using a recent version of the package.